# SQL Server datetime convert function equivalent to postgresql (pivotal hawq)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, datetime, hawq

We have following SQL script in SQL Server 2012. We are about to write similar script in postgresql (HAWQ 1.3.1) at database conversion

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT 
          SUM(b.OrderValue) AS OrderValue, b.OrderDate, b.Description 
      FROM 
          (SELECT * 
           FROM tablename_2 rcd
           LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT Distinct 
                     afv.Item, afv.Description, afd.KeyField
                 FROM tablename_3 afd
                 JOIN tablename_3 afv ON afv.FormType = afd.FormType 
                                      AND afv.FieldName = afd.FieldName 
                                      AND afv.Item = afd.AlphaValue
                 WHERE
                      afd.FormType = 'CUS'
                      AND afd.FieldName = 'COR002') a ON a.KeyField = rcd.Customer 
           WHERE
               OrderDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()), 101)) b 
    GROUP BY
        b.OrderDate, b.Description) c ON rtr.CorpAcctName = c.Description
```

We tried and wrote the following script:

Above script compiled into postgresql ( VERSION HAWQ 1.3.1)

```
SELECT * from tablename_1  rtr LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT SUM(b."OrderValue") as OrderValue,b."OrderDate", b."Description" from
(SELECT *  from tablename_2 rcd
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT Distinct afv."Item", afv."Description", afd."KeyField"
FROM tablename_2 afd
  Join tablename_3 afv on afv."FormType" = afd."FormType" and afv."FieldName"=afd."FieldName" and afv."Item"=afd."AlphaValue"
Where   afd."FormType" = 'CUS'and afd."FieldName" = 'COR002') a
ON a."KeyField" =rcd."Customer" where "OrderDate">=TO_CHAR((CURRENT_DATE -(CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL '1 DAY)) ,'MM-DD-YYYY')) b 
group by b."OrderDate", b."Description") c
on rtr."CorpAcctName"=c."Description"
```

**Also tried with :**

- When we tried to convert ms sql server convert function into postgres
  for orderdate column comparison of OrderDate must reflect as 
  'MM-01-YYYY'(desired result) which is actually coming '00-01-0000'
  not desired.instead we are looking for outcome as '11-01-2015'

**

- What will be the convert() function expression in postgresql for
  getting desired result?

**

Comment: What data type is `OrderDate`? In this expression `(CURRENT_DATE -(CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL '1 DAY))` you are missing the "closing" single quote for `'1 day'`. The expression also doesn't make sense at all - it will always return the _number_ 1. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: If it is a date, then why are you comparing it to a string? You probably want a simple `orderdate >= current_date - 1` if you want to get everything after "yesterday"

Comment: i want to achieve from my current_date always it provides 'MM-01-2015' FOR EX 11-14-2015  will be 11-01-2015.

Comment: You just said the data type for `orderdate` is `date` - a `date` doesn't have a "format" and you sure can't have a string like `'MM-01-2015'` in a `date` column. `current_date` is a function in Postgres that returns well, the current date. You can't have anything like `'MM-01-2015'` "in" that either

Comment: i wanted to achieve first day of month  from my current_date

Comment: i tried  test=# select TO_CHAR((CURRENT_DATE -(CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL '1 DAY')) ,'MM-DD-YYYY')                                                                                  ;
  to_char
------------
 00-01-0000
(1 row)

Comment: but we  want outcome as  11-01-2015.not sure if this is way to convert function in postgres. also posted sql server query convert function here.

Comment: Yes, I will make try on this date_trunc function.let you know the outcome if it is solve my purpose. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i wanted to achieve first day of month from my current_date

So you want everything that was created after the start of the current month.

A simple

```
where "OrderDate" >= date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

will do that.

Details on the `date_trunc()` method can be found in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

---

You should understand what your expression `TO_CHAR((CURRENT_DATE -(CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL '1 DAY')) ,'MM-DD-YYYY')` is doing so that you avoid that error in the future:

First: `current_date - interval '1 day'` subtracts an `interval` from a `date`, [which yields a `timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html): "yesterday" at `00:00:00`.

Then you subtract that from today's date, so `current_date - timestamp '2015-11-13 00:00:00.0'` (if today is 2015-11-14).

This yields an `interval`: `0 years 0 mons 1 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs`

You then pass that `interval` to the `to_char()` function which formats the passed interval. As it only has "1 day", no year, no month, the result of applying the format string `'MM-DD-YYYY'` on that does indeed yield `00-01-0000`.

You then compare this **character** value against a real `date` - which is also something you should not do.

---

<sup>You should really get rid of those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it</sup>

Comment: I just tested and implemented in my script at test database . it seems like solving my purpose. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @vickps: I added an explanation on what your expression is doing as you seem to have completely misunderstood how Postgres handles dates, timestamps and intervals

Comment: Yes i have lots of misconception in that .

Comment: This expanantion seems useful info for all people who is novice in postgresql. Thanks

Comment: @vickps: depends on where you come from. An Oracle user will not find this surprising.